# is it possible to connect a Windows 10 PC to a WiFi using a batch script or python?

Tags: windows-10, python, batch-file, wifi-configuration

I need to connect my Windows 10 PC to a WiFi automatically to test the WEP-128 encryption mode in a router. Basically, when I change the encryption mode in the router, I need to connect the PC to its SSID (I know the WEP-128 key). Do you guys know if I can do this from the cmd so I can write a batch script? Python could be good too!

Comment: So you want something that changes on the PC whenever it detects a change in the router?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to connect a Windows 10 PC to a WiFi using a batch script?](https://superuser.com/questions/1534147/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-windows-10-pc-to-a-wifi-using-a-batch-script)

Comment: @Anaksunaman yes, in this case, the encryption mode

Comment: maybe this helps [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47403038/connecting-to-wireless-network-in-batch-file-one-that-isnt-already-one-of-your#47495200)

Comment: @garbageoverflow yes! I used that one to create a new profile :) thanks a lot! the only issue I have right now is that the "netsh" command suggested as an answer sometimes doesn't really work and it shows a message saying "Connection request was completed successfully." so don't know what could be happening there

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the `netsh wlan` commands in a batchfile.

I think the syntax is...

`netsh wlan set HOSTEDNETWORK MODE=ALLOW SSID="your WiFi SSID name" KEY="Your WiFi password"`

Comment: When I use it to connect, I get the message "Connection request was completed successfully." but sometimes it doesn't do it. I have to do it manually. Any idea why this could be happening? or if there is a way to force the connection? thanks!! :)