# is it possible to connect a Windows 10 PC to a WiFi using a batch script?

Tags: wireless-networking, python, windows-10, batch

I need to connect my Windows 10 PC to a WiFi automatically to test the WEP-128 encryption mode in a router. Basically, when I change the encryption mode in the router, I need to connect the PC to its SSID (I know the WEP-128 key). Do you guys know if I can do this from the cmd so I can write a batch script? Python could be good too!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You need to have the wireless profile established, meaning you have to have that connection previously setup and saved. Once you connect the first time to YOURSSID, you will be able to use netsh to connect to it at any desired moment.

You then can connect with: `netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=YOURPROFILENAME`

You can list profiles using `netsh wlan show profile`

You can disconnect from the session using `netsh wlan disconnect`

Comment: I disconnect with the command you suggested, then I use the one to connect and I get the message "Connection request was completed successfully." but sometimes it doesn't do it. I have to do it manually. Any idea why this could be happening? or if there is a way to force the connection? thanks!! :)